# Delphi IDE data explorer

Tags: delphi, ide

Connection using FireDAC from within the IDE data explorer.

I'm trying to create a MSSQL connection using FireDAC from within the IDE data explorer, but when testing the connection, I'm always getting "Timeout Expired" error.
If create an application using FireDAC components (TFDConnection and TFDPhysMSSQLDriverLink1) with exact same parameters as within IDE data explorer connection, it just works fine.
What am I missing?

Comment: Do you open the connection with the FireDAC components in design time or runtime?

Comment: Design time, using TFDConnection and TFDPhysMSSQLDriverLink.

Comment: I would guess that the properties that you can see in the object inspector are different from what's used by the data explorer.

Comment: Well, how can I check or solve that?